# Hiding hidden inputs from radio button after clicking the next radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a confusion in my javascript code since I'm not familiar with js.I have three radio buttons with hidden inputs.Now, if i click radioBtn1, the hidden inputs will show up.What i want is if when i click the radioBtn2 or radioBtn3, the hidden inputs in radioBtn1 should be hidden again.So meaning to say when i click any radioBtn the second time around,the radioBtn that i've click first, its hidden inputs should be hidden again.

```js
function Allowance(select){
   if(select.value=='Allowance'){
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "block";
   }else{
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "none";
   }
} 
function Tuition(select){
  if(select.value=='Tuition Fee'){

    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "none";
   }
} 
function Supply(select){
  if(select.value=='School Supply'){
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="Allowance" id="test" onchange="Allowance(this)"> Allowance<br>
 <div id="allowance"  style="display: none;">
 <ul>
   <li>Food Allowance</li>
   <li>Transportation Allowance</li>
  </ul>
<label class="control-label">Money:</label>
   <input type="text">
</div>
  <input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="Tuition Fee" id="test" onchange="Tuition(this)"> Tution<br>
 <div id="tuition_fee"  style="display: none;">
 <ul>
   <li>Tuition Fee</li>
  </ul>
<label class="control-label">Money:</label>
   <input type="text">
</div>
  <input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="School Supply" id="test" onchange="Supply(this)"> School
 <div id="school_supply"  style="display: none;">
 <ul>
   <li>Books</li>
   <li>Uniform</li>
  </ul>
<label class="control-label">Money:</label>
   <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your code by using jquery. Please have a look on the below code, it may help you.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.sub_list').css('display','none');
 $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  $('.sub_list').css('display','none');
  $('#'+this.value).css('display','block');
  console.log(this.value);
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="allowance" id="test" > Allowance<br>
 <div id="allowance" class="sub_list"  >
 <ul>
   <li>Food Allowance</li>
   <li>Transportation Allowance</li>
  </ul>
<label class="control-label">Money:</label>
   <input type="text">
</div>
  <input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="tuition_fee" id="test2" > Tution<br>
 <div id="tuition_fee" class="sub_list"   >
 <ul>
   <li>Tuition Fee</li>
  </ul>
<label class="control-label">Money:</label>
   <input type="text">
</div>
  <input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="school_supply" id="test3" > School
 <div id="school_supply" class="sub_list"  >
 <ul>
   <li>Books</li>
   <li>Uniform</li>
  </ul>
<label class="control-label">Money:</label>
   <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: you are welcome, if you found it helpfull you can make it accepted answer so that others can also use that

Answer (score 0):

before showing an input close the others:

```
function Allowance(select){
   if(select.value=='Allowance'){   
     document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "block";
   }else{
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "none";
   }
} 
function Tuition(select){
  if(select.value=='Tuition Fee'){
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "none";
   }
} 
function Supply(select){
  if(select.value=='School Supply'){
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your logic is partial, you are showing the fields, but not hiding other fields.

```
function Allowance(select){
   if(select.value=="Allowance"){
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "none";
   }
} 
function Tuition(select){
  if(select.value=='Tuition Fee'){
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "none";
   } 
} 
function Supply(select){
  if(select.value=='School Supply'){
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "block";
   }
}
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/vjb2dnpg/